# Disqus Comment Counter stops working when I put a unique id number in href

Tags: disqus

Disqus is supposed to tell you how many comments you have.  I however have found that If I put a unique id into my comment url it stops displaying the number of comments.

If I link to: `<a href="/artcomment/<?=$uniqueID?>#disqus_thread">0 Comments</a>` Users can correctly add comments to individual art, however the 0 doesn't update to list how many comments!  If I instead link to `<a href="comment.php#disqus_thread">0 Comments</a>` it updates the 0 to show how many comments there are.  The problem is without the unique identifier all comments just end up on one page instead of multiple pages.  I have also tried putting in `data-disqus-identifier="article_<?=$uniqueID?>_identifier"` on my comment link as described in their setup instructions.  It didn't help to display how many comments there was.

I even tried to write a preg_match script to scrape the comment number off of the comment page.  However the entire comments.php page is just a javascript that generates content.  It does not have the comment number in the source code so I am at a loss.

Comment: There's probably a mismatch with your actual URL, and the URL stored with your Disqus thread. Same for the custom identifier, so it's impossible to tell what the real issue is. Check out the following link and update the question with what you find: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472099

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it takes time for the comment counter to update.  The comments I left yesterday showed "1 Comment" today.   You just need to be patient for the counter to work.